# How to delete all product data in magento2 database? **not possible**

Tags: php, mysql, datatable, magento2, truncate

someone who had same trouble as me in past?

It is about **deleting all product data in magento2 shop system**! I am fighting with the database, I guess the function for deleting in magento2 is not working properly. After I deleted all product data by using SKU-import there are still data in category tree of backend left.

E.g. in magento2 own filter (material, price, color, …) I placed filter on left side in category view in order to enable customers to filter the results. Even if I deleted the database there will be still products shown.

PS: I used "TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_product;" to empty the category tree.

**My question: Is there anyone out there who managed it to kill 100 % of product data out of database absolutely clearly without getting fragments left?**

Where the hell are the scraps causing my issue? Anyone expert? Some clues really needed and warmyl welcome, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 1 I used magmi for cleaning a store catalog. It did the job really good and very fast. You may try using fork of magmi for Magento 2 - https://github.com/macopedia/magmi-git

Comment: Hi Antisly, thank you for your idea, I 'll give it a try!

Comment: Hi Antisly, hello world. Just a quick feedback to your clue: I used magmi which is still in developer mode for magento2. It causes an error as 3 tables are missing in my shop (//"catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing", //"catalog_product_entity_group_price",//"catalog_product_enabled_index",). After modifying the Clear Catalog v1.0.4 tool starting from row 63 as following...